# Is it possible to update a document using its own properties?

Tags: mongodb

I've tried and to no avail, heres the example:

```js
db.examples.insert({
  _id: 1,
  topLevelValue: 10,
  values: [
    {value: 10},
    {value: 14},
    {value: 5}
  ]
})

db.examples.updateOne({_id: 1}, {
  $set: {
    'values.$.calculatedValue': {
       $divide: ['values.$.value', '$topLevelValue']
    }
  }
})
```

The expected outcome is that all the values have a new  field `calculatedValue` which is the result of its value divided by the `topLevelValue`

I am not saying this SHOULD work, I am saying that if what I want to do is possible via mongodb updates.

Comment: check out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents/

Comment: You can try [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) - this allows using its own document's properties.